# Gnome 3 icon size and sorting windows 7/10 style

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome-shell-extensions

I would like a suggestion for a gnome extensions that let me sort icons on 'Files' like windows on 'Explorer'.

It's been two days searching on google and browsing on gnome extensions site for a extension that allow me do this.

I want to have some folders in grid view and another folders in list view.
On windows I can set this once in that folder and this configuration will stick only in that folder.

Likewise the icon size, if I set a gigantic icon size for one folder, close the folder, the next time that I open that folder, only that folder will have that gigantic icon size (good for folder with images)

I'm using fedora 27 workstation.

Comment: Unfortunately this would have to be done in Nautilus, a Gnome Shell extension can't monkey-patch desktop applications. I'm not convinced a Nautilus extension *could* do it, but at least I don't know of one that does.

Comment: Ok, at this point i already gave up, but gonna try to search something for nautilus. I didn't know that the name of "files" is naultilus. i always developed in windows using 'explorer', and i'm trying full linux now. I got a lot to learn yet.

Comment: It's a bit confusing for sure, sometimes linux programs have a "project" name such as Nautilus and a "user facing" name like Files (another example might be Firefox, which might be sometimes render Web Browser).

Answer (score 0):

Dophin File Manager

It comes with Fedora Spin KDE Plasma

https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/kde/

I like it more the cinnamon spin, so I installed Dolphin on the cinnamon version.

https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/cinnamon/